# sorting a file containing huge amount of data

Tags: time-complexity, array-algorithms

Consider a file containing `N` words with one word per line.The file is too big so whole of it connot be read in memory at one time.

My ans:
Divide the file into `k chunks`.So size of each chunk `x = N/k`

Read one chunk into memory at a time and sort it and write back to the file.Sort all k chunks.

Now do a `k way merge`.

Analying total time complexity. How can i do it?

Time for sorting each chunk = `xlogx` (assuming i use quick sort)

Time for merging k chunks = `klogk` (is it??)

So total time complexity =`??`

Am week at analying time complexity

Comment: Well, complexity isn't anything.
You should also consider that reading from disk is slower than from memory.

Also i think that time for merging is NlogN. So total complexity is NlogN BUT you should consider how much it take to load data from disk to memory (you're doing it more than 2N times).

Comment: Quick note is that quicksort is still O(n^2) worst time, though still O(n log n) average. Mergesort's average and worst time is O(n log n)

Answer (score 1):

Each chunk is of size N/k and the number of chunks is k.

So, total time complexity would be

Reading of N/k chunks + Sorting each of those chunks i.e., O( N/k klogk) + Merging each [part] of those k chunks O( Nk ) + File Writing.

So, it would be IO Time + O(Nlogk)

I am learning these things too...so it would be great if someone can analyze and correct me if im wrong here..

-Pavan.